# ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’ in rstudio - Debian jessie 8.0

Tags: r, debian, rlang

I am trying to install 'forecast' package in R (version 3.1.1 64bit) on my Debian jessie machine.

I have installed other R packages required for my analyses. However, when I try to install 'forecast' package it require dependencies, namely, rlang, tipple and ggplot2. It looks from the error log (shown below) tipple and ggplot2 requires rlang to be installed for them to be installed.

> gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c sexp.c -o sexp.o
>
> gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c splice.c -o splice.o
>
> In file included from splice.c:2:0:
>
> vector.h: In function ‘namespace_rlang_sym’:
>
> vector.h:94:19: error: ‘R_DoubleColonSymbol’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>     return(Rf_lang3(R_DoubleColonSymbol, rlang_sym, sym));
>                      ^
>   vector.h:94:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
>
> /usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:128: recipe for target 'splice.o' failed
>
> make: *** [splice.o] Error 1
>
> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’
>
> - removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rlang’
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>    installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status
>   ERROR: dependency ‘rlang’ is not available for package ‘tibble’
>   * removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/tibble’
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>    installation of package ‘tibble’ had non-zero exit status
>   ERROR: dependency ‘tibble’ is not available for package ‘ggplot2’
>   * removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/ggplot2’
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>    installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
>   ERROR: dependency ‘ggplot2’ is not available for package ‘forecast’
>   * removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/forecast’
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>    installation of package ‘forecast’ had non-zero exit status

rlang installation fails with the above error message. Any expert help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Next version of rlang (to be released sometime late August) will be compatible with R 3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is your R version, based on [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/rlang/issues/143) which generates the [same error](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/tidyverse/tibble/build/1.0.159/job/4xm3kyip9y3vgty9#L1037). Some of the "tidyverse" packages such as `tibble` and `rlang` are quite recent and require newer R versions.

So: try updating your R version. The latest is 3.4.0.

Comment: Upgrading the version (3.1.1-> 3.4.0) worked for me.

Comment: Hi, I am using version 3.4.1 still having the problem, btw I just updated R core from 3.4.0 to 3.4.1, the error messages are `/usr/include/R/Rinternals.h:940:13: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘const char* Rf_reEnc(const char*, cetype_t, cetype_t, int)’ [-fpermissive]const char *Rf_reEnc(const char *x, cetype_t ce_in, cetype_t ce_out, int subst);`